# Genetic Algorithm - deciding on the number of children to generate

Tags: genetic-algorithm

If I am to build a genetic algorithm  with

- Tournament selection
- box crossover (Recombination)
- Gaussian mutation
- population replacement with offstring

I would like to know the following?

should i offspring be generated for each pair or parents or two? If not  should the number of offspring  created  be  a parameterized ?

Thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: The usual strategy is to select the top X% of the population, then cross them over to fill out the rest of the pool. For example, select 25 out of 100, and create 75 cross-overs. There's no magic number here.

Comment: So basically I can create as many offspring I would like  from the parents ?

Comment: A high ratio of offspring to parents means the population will be mixed together more aggressively. This may have the effect of adding too much chaos to your system. Likewise having a ratio too low means it may take a long time to converge on a solution. Experiment with different ratios to see how they affect finding solutions in your problem domain.